# The exercise package in list form

Tags: lists, exercises

I would like --- using the `exercise` package --- to make lists of exercises using the `ExerciseList` environment. The output is supposed to look like in the below example.

[image: Example from book]

The exercises are to be indented as shown, with the number to the left, like in an ordinary list environment. Can this be done within the `exercise` package?

**EDIT:** In order to please @cfr, I hereby publish my own attempts at solving this problem. The code crashes painfully:

```
\documentclass[openright,book]{memoir}

%Dansk sprog:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
%\OnehalfSpacing %hvis der oenskes halvanden linjeafstand

%Pakker
\usepackage[noDcommand]{kpfonts} % the kpfonts font
\usepackage{%
    amsmath,graphicx,enumerate,amstext,geometry,array,xfrac,bm,mathtools,siunitx,
    %tikz, pgfplots
    etoolbox, xparse, %til subexc
    fixltx2e, %fikser et par bugs i LaTeX-kernen
    microtype, %smaa fiks, der goer tekst lettere at laese
    varioref,
    }

\usepackage{exercise}
\renewcommand\ExerciseListName{} % I don't want any word like "exercise" anywhere
\renewcommand\ExerciseHeaderTitle{\Exercisetitle}

\renewcommand{\ExerciseListHeader}{\ExerciseHeaderDifficulty%
    \item[\ExerciseHeaderNB]\ExerciseHeaderTitle\ %
    \ExerciseHeaderOrigin\ignorespaces}

\renewenvironment{ExerciseList}{\enumerate[1]\beginExerciseListEnv}{\endExerciseListEnv\endenumerate}


\begin{document}

\begin{ExerciseList}
    \Exercise What is this?
    \Exercise What is that
    \Question What in the world?
    \subQuestion What is this?
    \ExeText We define $x = y$.
\end{ExerciseList}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With a little effort a very similar layout is doable with [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets). If you like I'll provide an answer with it. (I don't know if a similar thing is possible with `exercise`...)

Comment: Why don't you use a list?

Comment: According to the documentation `ExerciseList` is just a `list` environment and you can customise it as you will. What, if anything, have you actually tried? Note that questions which just post an image and ask how to make it are not really suitable for this site and they leave you at the mercy of a small band of procrastinators looking for something to do. You will get more, better and faster responses if you show you've made some effort by posting a Minimal (non-)Working Example. It is usually easier to understand what people want in this case as well.

Comment: @cgnieder, thank you, that would be nice :-) .

Comment: @HarishKumar Kumar, because automatic question environments have features that I like to use and which ease typing. First of all, you can easily go back and forth between subquestions and main text.

Comment: @cfr, I think you might want to improve your politeness a bit. It might be that you're frustrated of some other people's way of asking questions, but I don't want to take the blame for that. In fact, I did experiment with redefining `ExerciseList` to include a list and `Exercise` to include an `\item` command. Whatever I did, it crashed painfully, and I really saw no point in including the failed source codes. Perhaps I was wrong, but please be nice. anyway.

Comment: @cfr, I hope you're happy to see that I did add my own attempts now.

Comment: @Gaussler Note that an `exsheets` will be quite different from `exercise`. (I'll post a solution as soon as I have the time). BTW: cfr just told you what the community understanding of this site is. I'm sure he/she didn't want to be impolite. cfr is right: posting a minimal working example usually improves chances to get an answer quite a lot: now people have some code to start with when they want to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in the comments an `exsheets` solution for such a layout was welcomed here it is... the usage is quite different from the `exercise` package, though...

The solution contains of several steps:

- Wrap KOMA-Script's `addmargin` environment around the `question` environment with the help of `etoolbox`'s `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment`. This gets the question bodies indented by the specified margin (`3em` in the example below). The `addmargin` environment is provided by the `scrextend` package so it can be used with other classes, too.
- Declare a new heading instance inspired by `margin-nr` instance described in the `exsheets` manual which uses the same margin as set by the `addmargin` environment (`3em` in the example below) to place the question number aligned with the text margin.
- Set up `exsheets` to use the new instance and add some options for in-section numbering.

This is how the document from the code below looks like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}% not needed with a KOMA-Script class, provides the
                      % `addmargin' environment

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{mylist}{default}{
  runin = true ,
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]number[l,vc](-3em,0pt) ; % 3em = indent of question body
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\linewidth+\marginparsep,0pt)
  }
}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings = mylist , % use the new headings instance
  headings-format = \normalfont ,
  counter-format = se.qu ,
  counter-within = section
}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
% 3em = indent of question body :
\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\addmargin[3em]{0em}}
\AtEndEnvironment{question}{\endaddmargin}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{10}

\section*{Exercises}
\subsection*{Exercises to section \thesection}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[10]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```